# Check if boundingRectWithSize was needed to wrap attributed string

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to do a check to see if my UILabel needed its last line truncated and that "NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail" was actually used. I can visually see the truncation with tail, but I want to create a condition on whether or not the "NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail" was needed or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the size with `boundingRectWithSize` based on the font attributes and text and compare it to the label size.